# Groupby and transform across a group, not within it

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the third column of this dataframe, given the first two columns.

I can't work out what to search for, it's like a within version of `groupby('group')['weeklyTotal'].cumsum()`??

I know I could pull out those two columns, make them distinct, then do the groupby cumsum, but would much prefer to have this within the same dataframe.

To save a tiny bit of pain, here's an example dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'], 'weeklyTotal':[1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2]})`

| Group | WeeklyTotal | CumulativeTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| C | 2 | 6 |
| C | 2 | 6 |
| C | 2 | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only one row per group with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), compute the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values:

```
df['CumulativeTotal'] = df['group'].map(df.drop_duplicates(subset='group')
                                          .set_index('group')['weeklyTotal']
                                          .cumsum()
                                       )
```

Or, using a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['CumulativeTotal'] = (df['weeklyTotal']
                         .mask(df['group'].duplicated(), 0)
                         .cumsum()
                        )
```

Output:

```
  group  weeklyTotal  CumulativeTotal
0     A            1                1
1     A            1                1
2     A            1                1
3     B            3                4
4     B            3                4
5     B            3                4
6     C            2                6
7     C            2                6
8     C            2                6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
m = df['group'].ne(df['group'].shift())
m.mul(df['weeklyTotal']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    6
7    6
8    6
```